# How to register Vue component in Laravel Framework?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

There is some issue in the Laravel + Vue Project.
The error is like this:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <packages> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Please help me.

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a webpack.mix.js file,
which should set your entry point like so :

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
```

and in your blade layout you should use this file :

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

You should be able to create your vue app and register global components in your app.js

```
Vue.component('packages', Packages);
```

or for vue  3 :

```
const app = createApp({})

app.component('packages', Packages);
```